# Law of Iterated Expectation for a Probability

Tags: probability, expected-value

In my understanding of a derivation, the following statement seems to be used:
$$Pr[V\leq X]=E[Pr[V\leq X|X]]$$
where both $X$ and $V$ are random variables.

Is this a kind of the law of iterated expectation?

Comment: Start from RHS. Use the definition. See what happens. Whether you can land to the LHS. Now is it the law of iterated expectation? While doing, it would be clear, by then.

Comment: Write $\mathbb P(V\le X)$ as $\mathbb E[\mathbb I_{V\le X}]$